# I cannot install packages via the terminal "connection failed", but can browse internet

Tags: apt

My internet connection is working as I can access the web through firefox but I get a connection failed message while trying to install packages via the terminal or synaptic.

```
Ign:1 http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libcurl4 amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8

Ign:2 http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 curl amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8

Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libcurl4 amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8

Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 curl amd64 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8

Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.24 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4_7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.24 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

That's the error message highlighted above.

It was working yesterday and I've tried the following commands,

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

nothing worked. runnning the command

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4_7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb
```

shows this error

```
--2020-01-08 03:56:06--  (try: 2)  http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4_7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb
Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (security.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.24|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

--2020-01-08 03:56:08--  (try: 3)  http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4_7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb
Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (security.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.24|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying
```

I'd be glad if anyone could help.

Comment: Try region settings. Where is ng

Comment: ng is Nigeria, that's where I live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few reasons why this can be happening:

- Your ISP is blocking the connection. Use a vpn. (happened with me)
- The servers are down. (Very unlikely)
- You're too far away from the server. (You can change your repository mirror)
- If you're on a corporate or school network it may require use of a proxy.

> Tip: Try accessing those links with Firefox.

Comment: It's working now. I restarted my computer a couple of times and it seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same as I was using the office net which has enabled some my  ISP blocking the connection which causes to getting some  error while installing the package using the Linux terminal

```
Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
```

Here's how I fix it up

Go to Ubuntu Software Store and choose **Software and Updates**

[image: screenshot]

Then change the download from whatever it is currently to **Main Server**

[image: settings dialog]

It may require some time to update the package cache - let it complete

[image: progress message - updating cache]

After that try again; your issue will be resolved.

Comment: If the problem was something to do with your office ISP, switching to the main server wouldn't fix it. However, switching to the main server would help if there was a problem with the local mirror, which may have been the case for Kehinde (seems the problem went away after a while; likely the local issue was fixed) so this answer would probably have helped. I suggest editing this to remove the confusing info about your ISP - the solution in that case would probably be to adjust proxy configuration.